# VB.NET fill out object fields on creation

Tags: vb.net

In C# when creating an object we can also (at the same time) fill out its properties. Is this possible in VB.NET?

For example:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject
{
   Name = "Bill",
   Age = 50
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
Dim obj As New MyObject With { .Name = "Bill", .Age = 50 }
```

Two important things:

1. Use `With` keyword after class name and before `{ ... }`
2. Property names have to be prefixed with a dot, so you have to use `.Name` instead of `Name`

For collection initializers use `From` keyword:

```
Dim obj as New List(Of String) From { "String1", "String2" }
```